# MySQL multiple "left join" and "having"

Tags: mysql, left-join, counting, having

I have tables:

1.Workers(id,name)

2.BonusPenalties(id,worker_id,type,worker_id,value)

3.Fouls(id,worker_id,value)

for BonusPenalties column "type" can be "0" or "1" where 0 - is the bonus, 1 - is the penalty

so I need to be able to filter workers by the number of bonuses / penalties / fouls

Something like `where count(BonusPenalties.id) > 5(for penalties) and count(BonusPenalties.id) >7(for bonuses) and count(Fouls.id) < 100`

I tried to join this tables by left join and using "HAVING" but results goes wrong

Comment: Combine tables 2 and 3 into one table. Use ENUM datatype for `type` column with 3 possible values.

Comment: *but results goes wrong* Join multiplying?

Comment: @Akina, can you please write the example for joining if I will combine tables 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> write the example for joining if I will combine tables 2 and 3

```sql
CREATE TABLE effects (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    worker_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_worker_id REFERENCES worker (worker_id),
    type ENUM('bonus', 'penalty', 'foul') NOT NULL,
    value DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Now there is no joining multiplying, and you may use something like

```sql
HAVING SUM(type='bonus') > 2
   AND SUM(type='foul') = 0
```

or

```sql
HAVING SUM(type='bonus') > 2 -- check bonuses amount
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN type='foul' THEN value ELSE 0 END) < 1000 -- check total sum of fouls
```

after GROUP BY.

Comment: thanks! now I can filter by penalties and bonuses. But what can I do if there is no posibility to combine fouls with bonuspenalties

Comment: @Baurzhan Use UNION ALL subquery with data transforming (encode fouls as, for example, type=2). Or maybe even a view (if execution speed is not a problem). For example...